# PHP - Server code and html code

Tags: php

I'm programming a website and I have seen two approaches when programming in PHP:

- To mix php and html in one .php file.

or

- To have html code in .html file and php code in .php file.

Which one is the best way to go?

I guess each one have their pros and cons.  So, which one should I choose?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) & [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 2):

2nd option is from far the best.

Imagine your php is at the server and your html at the client, they are talking together... The php is supposed to fill in the values (model) only, while the html or javascript should handle all what is usually called the "view".

This is all about code organization, quality management and maintainability.

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have the html code in a `.html` file. The `html` could be in a `.php` file but the business logic can be separate from the presentation ( controller can be separate from the view ). In terms of a pattern this is called the MVC pattern. The model, view and controller. It all depends on how complex your project is, MVC is not a dogma, it's a pattern that just makes code easier to maintain and organize as the project grows in complexity. So in summary, it depends on the complexity of your project.